# Enzyme Catalysis Equation

Tags: chemistry

I'm trying to build an enzyme catalysis equation and end up like this:

```
\begin{equation}\label{QSSA-cat-MM}
E 
\begin{matrix*}[l]
\rotatebox{40}{$\xrightleftharpoons[k_{-1}]{{[S]}k_1}$}\\[-0.5em]
\rotatebox{-40}{$\xrightleftharpoons[k_{-1}]{{[S]}k_1}$}\\[1em]
\end{matrix*}
\begin{matrix*}[l]
\hspace{1.7cm} E+P\\[-1em]
ES \hspace{0.1cm} \rotatebox{40}{$\xrightarrow{k_{cat}}$} \\[-1.3em]
\hspace{0.6cm} \rotatebox{-40}{$\xrightleftharpoons[k_{-1}]{{[S]}k_1}$\\[0em]
\hspace{0.6cm} \rotatebox{40}{$\xrightleftharpoons[k_{-1}]{{[S]}k_1}$}\\[-1em]
SE \hspace{0.1cm} \rotatebox{-40}{$\xrightarrow{k_{cat}}$} \\[-1em] 
\hspace{1.5cm} E+P
\end{matrix*} 
\hspace{-1cm} SES  \xrightarrow{k_{cat}}E+2P
\end{equation}
```

The shape is exactly this, but it's not aligned.

There is some other way to do this?

Comment: Not aligned in which way? After adding the necessary closing brace `}` I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l50ak.png) as output. Are you referring to the 3 right-most expressions? If so, what alignment were you interested in? Be specific.

Comment: It is not symmetric

Comment: But there are sooo nice packages like chemfig around. Or is there a reason you don't like those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option, depending on what you mean by *symmetric*:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,graphicx,eqparbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  E 
  \begin{matrix*}[l]
    \rotatebox{40}{$\xrightleftharpoons[k_{-1}]{{[S]}k_1}$} \\[-0.5em]
    \rotatebox{-40}{$\xrightleftharpoons[k_{-1}]{{[S]}k_1}$} \\[1em]
  \end{matrix*}
  \begin{matrix*}[l]
    \hspace{1.7cm} E+P\\[-1em]
    ES \hspace{0.1cm} \rotatebox{40}{$\xrightarrow{k_{cat}}$} \\[-1.3em]
    \hspace{0.6cm} \rotatebox{-40}{$\xrightleftharpoons[k_{-1}]{{[S]}k_1}$} \\[0em]
    \hspace{0.6cm} \rotatebox{40}{$\xrightleftharpoons[k_{-1}]{{[S]}k_1}$} \\[-1em]
    SE \hspace{0.1cm} \rotatebox{-40}{$\xrightarrow{k_{cat}}$} \\[-1em] 
    \hspace{1.5cm} E+P
  \end{matrix*} 
  \hspace{-1cm} SES \xrightarrow{k_{cat}}E+2P
\end{equation}

\bigskip

\begin{equation}
  E 
  \begin{array}{ @{} c @{} }
    \eqmakebox[R1]{\rotatebox{ 40}{$\xrightleftharpoons[k_{-1}]{{[S]}k_1}$}} \\
    \eqmakebox[R1]{\rotatebox{-40}{$\xrightleftharpoons[k_{-1}]{{[S]}k_1}$}}
  \end{array}
  \begin{array}{ @{} c @{} }
    \raisebox{2\normalbaselineskip}{\eqmakebox[R2]{$ES$}} \\
    \raisebox{-2.7\normalbaselineskip}{\eqmakebox[R2]{$SE$}}
  \end{array}
  \begin{array}{ @{} c @{} }
    \rotatebox{40}{$\xrightarrow{k_{\text{cat}}}$} \\
    \rotatebox{-40}{$\xrightleftharpoons[k_{-1}]{{[S]}k_1}$} \\
    \rotatebox{ 40}{$\xrightleftharpoons[k_{-1}]{{[S]}k_1}$} \\
    \rotatebox{-40}{$\xrightarrow{k_{\text{cat}}}$}
  \end{array}
  \begin{array}{ @{} l @{} }
    \raisebox{3\normalbaselineskip}{\eqmakebox[R4][l]{$E + P$}} \\
    \eqmakebox[R4][l]{$SES$}\xrightarrow{k_{\text{cat}}} E + 2P \\
    \raisebox{-4\normalbaselineskip}{\eqmakebox[R4][l]{$E + P$}}
  \end{array}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Original display:

[image]

Updated display:

[image]